# PHP exec return openssl error

Tags: php, linux, svn, openssl, xampp

I want somehow from web access svn repository end get some data from it. I use XAMPP for Linux v5.6.28 (PHP 5.6.28) end tried to make svn.so, but I could not create it, because of openssl error. Now I' trying to call svn command with php exec, but still same error:

> svn: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libserf-1.so.1:
>   symbol GENERAL_NAME_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file
>   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

PHP script I use:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('svn info 2>&1');
print_r($output);
?>
```

If I change it to this:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('openssl version 2>&1');
print_r($output);
?>
```

I get this error:

> openssl: /opt/lampp/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not
>   found (required by openssl) openssl:
>   /opt/lampp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version`OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found
>   (required by openssl) openssl: /opt/lampp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0:
>   version `OPENSSL_1.0.2g' not found (required by openssl)

Everything works fine from console, but somehow not working from web. Any ideas, how to fix this in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Are you sure you have the php extension for openssl installed.  Take a look at [OpenSSL extension for PHP](http://serverfault.com/questions/348613/openssl-extension-for-php-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Also, have you replaced the system's version of OpenSSL with a different version that is ***not*** binary compatible? Or is there a second version of OpenSSL somewhere that is ***not*** binary compatible? This smells of that sort of memory error.

Comment: phpinfo() return "SSL Version  OpenSSL/1.0.2j". XAMPP latest release has it by default.

Comment: My ubuntu has OpenSSL 1.0.2g.